# What is the correct way to run a non-API service in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I understand Quarkus owns the main thread, but there doesn't seem to be a clean way to start a service that doesn't provide REST endpoints. I have a service that connects to a data source and writes the data stream to a database, with no API. The best solution I can find is to observe the startup event:

`fun onStart(@Observes event: StartupEvent)`

And then inject an instance of my service and start it there.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What is your use case ?

There are many ways to start up a service: 
- listening to system/CDI events like you did, 
- using a scheduler (see Quarkus guide),
- using messaging like JMS or Kafka by listening to incoming messages,
- using Apache Camel you can trigger your service by listening to almost anything like: jms, files, timers, email, etc.

Comment: Like I said in the question, it's very simple, the service's job is to startup, connect to a remote web-socket and persist the stream of data to a database. Nothing more. It seems like the best/only option then is to handle the start up event, because there will be no external trigger like a Kafka message for example..